# Making flags with conditions using Pentaho/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I'm trying to optimize my code with a better way to do this.
I have a variable "hour". I need to make flags like this:

```
if (hour == 0) {flag12AM = 'yes'} 
else {flag12AM == 'no'}

if (hour == 0 || hour == 1) {flag1AM = 'yes'} 
else {flag1AM == 'no'}

if (hour == 0 || hour == 1 || hour == 2) {flag2AM = 'yes'} 
else {flag2AM == 'no'}

[...]

if (hour == 0 || hour == 1 [...] || hour == 23) {flag23PM = 'yes'} 
else {flag23PM == 'no'}
```

Could I use a loop to do that? I'm using Pentaho, so, if there's any step that do this job, please, let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: Start by not using 24 different flag variables.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful for you:

```
var h = 20;
[...Array(24).fill().map((v, i) => i + 1)]
    .forEach((v) => 
         console.log([...Array(v).fill().map((h, i) => i)]
                        .reduce((result, currentValue) => result || (h == currentValue), false), v))
```

Comment: That solution won’t work in his context, which is Pentaho. JS code is run in Rhino, and doesn’t support the syntax, nor the techniques used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data grid step to generate all flag values and then look up the hour and retrieve all flags.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, using **Modified Java Script Value** step, you can calculate all the flags with a for loop and then assign and export the values to specific flag names

```
var flags = []

for (i=0; i<24; i++) {
    flags[i] = hour <= i ? "yes" : "no"
}

var flag12AM = flags[0]
var flag1AM  = flags[1]
var flag2AM  = flags[2]
....
var flag23PM = flags[23]
```

Or use **Scripting** -> **Formula** step

```
New field: flag12AM
Formula: IF([hour]<=0;"yes";"no")
Value type: String
```

do the similar to all other fields.

[image]